# How to configure openstack all in one with self-service network

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

Hi I try to setup openstack with self served network to get openstack LBaaS, FWaaS and VPNaaS. When i tried that with provided network (using RDO project) i getting warning error "Parameter CONFIG_NEUTRON_L2_AGENT: You have choosen OVN neutron backend. Note that this backend does not support LBaaS, VPNaaS or FWaaS services. Geneve will be used as encapsulation method for tenant networks"

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
# hostnamectl set-hostname example.linvx.com.br
# hostnamectl set-hostname example.local.domain
```

or

```
# dnf remove hiera -y
# dnf config-manager --disable epel
# dnf install -y openstack-packstack
```

3 - Install OVN: https://docs.ovn.org/en/latest/intro/install/general.html#general-bootstrapping

Good lvck!! the sovrce be with yov!!

Answer (score 0):

Which OS? Which releases, versions, repos of packstack?
try get ovt the car, I mean, back a version...

```
# sudo dnf remove -y centos-release-openstack-wallaby
# sudo dnf install -y centos-release-openstack-victoria
```